# Ember Build not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I have an ember app that works by itself, I am able to run the server and see it. I then ran `ember build`, and opened up the /dist/index.html in my browser. I was unable to load any css or js in the /dist/assets folder, and it was instead looking at my root filesystem. I opened up index.html and commented out the `<base href='/'>`. After doing that I was able to load the css, and js. However, I am getting a security issue. What am I doing wrong with this build process, and should I have to comment out `<base href='/'>`?

The security issue I got was `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a modern SPA's starting html directly with its `file://...` in a browser, it will almost never work. Browsers treat files opened from the local file system different then html sent by a server.

So what you *should* do is always use a webserver to deploy your files to your browser. In a typical ember app you should also deploy the app to the root folder, and configure your webserver to always sent the `index.html` out if no other file matches the requested path, so that the ember router can start doing its own routing.

This can be done in almost *every* webserver, like apache, nginx, IIS, and anything else. But how to do this on a special webserver is a question not about ember but about that webserver.